# X3: Albion Prelude: How do I stop my SETA Interruptions?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

When I'm attacking Argon stations as a Terran, an announcer of sorts keep's informing me that Argon fighters have been dispatched with orders to kill [they never arrive] with almost every salvo from my ship, which interrupts my SETA each time.
Is there a way to get him to shut up so I can bombard stations with SETA active to my hearts content?